# Curl of a vector field $x \mapsto A x$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, vector-fields

> Given a vector field $F = Ax$, where $A \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ and $x \in \mathbb R^2$, find the curl of $F$.

In this case, if we know that the matrix is a constant is it right for me to conclude that it is a constant vector field and hence it has a $div F = 0$ and $curl F = 0$? How to provide a proof for this?

Comment: The curl is an operator applied on $3$-dimensional vector fields, not on $2$-dimensional vector fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the vector field is **not** constant. The vector field, if the matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

is equal to $$f(x,y)=(ax+by, cx+dy)$$

which is pretty far from being constant...

Comment: So being told that the 2x2 matrix is a constant matrix doesn't make a difference at all?

Comment: @Lello It does make a difference. If the matrix weren't constant, then you couldn't calculate the curl. (because then you wouldn't have $ax+by$, but instead $a(x,y) x + b(x,y)y$, where $a$ and $b$ are some (unknown) functions.